# Statement blocks in SQL SELECT using IF ELSE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement

I'm trying to return different data depending on a variable in a `SELECT`. Something like this:

```
SELECT
   IF @variable = 'YES'
      column1, column2
   ELSE
      column3
FROM TABLE
```

What is this the proper way to use the `IF` condition in SQL? Or is there a better alternative to what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an IF statement, but you'll need to set up multiple queries. You can use a CASE for selecting one column or another, but not to select one or multiple like in your question.

```
DECLARE @var INT = 1;

DECLARE @test TABLE (
    Col1 int,
    Col2 int,
    Col3 int
)

INSERT INTO @test VALUES (1,2,3)

IF @var = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT  Col1, Col2
    FROM    @test
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT  Col3
    FROM    @test
END
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to return a different number of columns, you'll need to use an `IF`:

```
IF @variable = 'YES'
BEGIN
    SELECT column1, column2
    FROM YourTable
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
    SELECT column3
    FROM YourTable
END
```

If you want different data on the same column (assuming the same datatype), you could use a `CASE`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @variable = 'YES' THEN column1 ELSE Column2 AS Data
FROM YourTable
```